# Creating multiple draggable Javascript objects with individual properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to create draggable objects that have each have their own properties. I am a beginner at Javascript with very minimal experience, and this is for a project that involves creating a simple circuit simulator.

So far, I have been able to drag, drop & clone components in a DOM courtesy of some very helpful stackoverflow-ers. But I am struggling to move on to the next bit, which is making each component unique, with editable properties such as name, type and coordinates, so that when I click on that object again, I can pull up something like a little pop-up menu that allows me to modify the properties of that specific object.
Would anyone be able to offer any pointers of how to go about doing it?

Here is the jsfiddle of what I have so far - http://jsfiddle.net/3Lnqocf3/

Any help is very much appreciated!

**Javascript -**

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".component").draggable({
        //  use a helper-clone that is append to 'body' so is not 'contained' by a pane
        helper: function() {
            return jQuery(this).clone().appendTo('body').css({
                'zIndex': 5
            });
        },
        cursor: 'move',
        containment: "document"
    });

    jQuery('.ui-layout-center').droppable({
        activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
        accept: '.component',
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            if (!ui.draggable.hasClass("dropped")) {
                var parentOffset = jQuery('.ui-layout-center').offset();
                var dropped = jQuery(ui.draggable).clone().addClass("dropped").draggable();
                dropped.css('left', (ui.position.left  - parentOffset.left) +'px');
                dropped.css('top', (ui.position.top - parentOffset.top) +'px');

                jQuery(this).append(dropped);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use `data`, see http://jsfiddle.net/3Lnqocf3/2/

Comment: It took me awhile to understand where you were coming from. Thanks for that artm that was exactly what I needed.